# Spring Batch Job Execution does not show in Executions Tab

Tags: spring-batch, spring-java-config, spring-xd

I have a Spring Batch job setup using JavaConfig (entirely through java code) which I deploy on a module in Spring XD. Typically, when you launch a job, you should see it in Spring XD's admin-ui under the Executions tab. Not mine, however, and I have no clue why. I've spent hours scouring through the documentation and looking for an answer, but I can't find anything.

Am I missing something? Is there something I need to put in my Job to make this work? What could cause Spring XD to not display a job's execution under Executions?

If you need me to provide logs or something, let me know, although I am not seeing any error in the Spring XD console output.

EDIT: This is how the job is defined int the code:

```
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("Job")
            .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
            .start(setupStep)
            .next(verifyStep)
            ...
            .next(zipFilesStep)
            .next(teardownStep)
            .build();
```

Comment: Providing some of your configuration would help.  That way we can be sure you're using the same `JobRepository` that Spring XD is looking at.

Comment: What do you mean by configuration? Since I'm using JavaConfig, my complete code is my config, no?

Answer (score 0):

Does this happen only at the Admin UI? Can you see the job executions when you run the XD shell command `job execution list`?

If you are sure the batch job gets executed but not getting listed then it appears a bug. Do you see any stacktrace at the admin log when the execution tab is clicked?

Comment: When running 'job execution list', I do not see anything. However, the adming log, I don't see any errors... it seems like everything is working fine.

Comment: To clarify, in the admin logs, I see my own code logs being printed.